# Machine Learning: Weighting Training Points by Importance

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, training-data

I have a set of labeled training data, and I am training a ML algorithm to predict the label. However, some of my data points are more important than others. Or, analogously, these points have less uncertainty than the others.

Is there a general method to include an importance-representing weight to each training point in the model? Are there instead some specific models which are capable of this while others are not?

I can imagine duplicating these points (and perhaps smearing their features slightly to avoid exact duplicates), or downsampling the less important points. Is there a more elegant way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Scikit-learn allows you to pass an array of sample weights while fitting the model. Vowpal Wabbit (an online ML library) also has this option.